# How to implement logic for the copy an attribute value to another attribute based on the attribute sets?

Tags: magento2, attributes, catalog

1. We have some attribute sets like BCDs, Polespears ...etc and respected attributes like **bcds_color**,    **polespears_color** ..etc would like to copy the value from attribute set based to **"ca_color"** attribute when admin save the product. Can you please guide me how to implement logic for this.
2. I have written code for copy an attribute while saving a product at admin end

> app/code/Demo/Copyattribute/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="Product Save After" instance="Demo\Copyattribute\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Demo/Copyattribute/Observer/Productsaveafter.php

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Copyattribute\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
     protected $_action;
     private $logger;
     /** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet **/
     protected $attributeSet;

     public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action $action,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet


         ){        
            $this->_action=$action;
            $this->logger = $logger;
            $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
         }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     try{

           $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/magento2.log');
           $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
           $logger->addWriter($writer);

           $productColorValue='';
           $store   = $observer->getStoreId();
           $product = $observer->getProduct();//product object
           $productId = $product->getId();         
           $attributeSetRepository = $this->attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
           //return $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();         
           $logger->info("Attribute Set Name".$attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName());
            //
             //Here Logic (or) code?
            //          

            $productColorValue=$product->getResource()->getAttribute('bcds_color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

            if($productColorValue == 'No')
            {
               $productColorValue='';
            }                    
            $this->_action->updateAttributes(array($productId), array('ca_color'=>$productColorValue),$store);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
             $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }

    }   
}
```

[image: requirement]